# Rails 3 has_one / belongs_to relationship with model in subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration, belongs-to, subdirectory, has-one

I'm trying to create a simple relationship but with a model in a subdirectory under Rails 3.2

I have a User class and each user has an email subscription..  Because There will be other types of subscriptions (which also fill be added to users) I put them in a subdirectory .  (My User happens to come from Devise but I suspect that won't matter.)

Here's the code

In `model/user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :email_sub

  before_create :build_email_subscription

  private

  def build_email_subscription
    Subscription::EmailSub.create(:is_subscribed => true, :user_id => self.id)
    true
  end
end
```

Note that I have also created a way to add a default subscription.

In `model/subscriptions/email_sub.rb`

```
class Subscriptions::EmailSub < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In addition to the migrations to create the two classes I created the following migration for the relationship.

```
class AddSubscriptionToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change_table :subscriptions_email_sub do |t|
    t.referneces :users
  end
end
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working. It doesn't seem to be generating the `user_id` column.

Comment: Note: referneces is misspelt.  I would also try using add_column subscriptions_email_sub user_id:integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I got it to work. I'm sharing and annotating my result for others to learn.

In `model/user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :email_sub, :class_name => "Subscriptions::EmailSub"

  before_create :build_email_subscription

  private

  def build_email_subscription
    build_email_sub(:announcements => true, :notifications => true, :master => true)
    true
  end
end
```

I expressly include the `class_name` to find the model in the subdirectory.  I used the `build_<attribute>` and passed in the parameters for three subscriptions (later to come in from a form but for now just setting defaults).

In `model/subscriptions/email_sub.rb`

```
class Subscriptions::EmailSub < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :announcements, :daily_deals, :master
  belongs_to :user
end
```

(I left the attributes out above since they're not really relevant to the issue but I'll expressly include them here for beginning users.)

Instead of a new migration I modified the original migration for the EmailSubs model.

```
class CreateSubscriptionsEmailSubs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :subscriptions_email_subs do |t|
      t.boolean :master
      t.boolean :daily_deals
      t.boolean :announcements

      t.references :user    # I added this line to the generated migration
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I added the `t.references` line.  Note that I had it plural before and not singular (in a migration the table name needs to be plural, the field singular).  t.references will know to look for the _id field given .

Hopefully this can help save some others some time.

Answer (score 0):

I would redo the way you set up your models. I don't think it's good practice to try and edit relationship tables that rails creates automatically.

For your model user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :subscriptions
    // Put whatever before_create logic here if that's still working correctly
end
```

Change subscription.rb to:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :subscription_type
end
```

Then make another model, subscription_type.rb

```
class SubscriptionType < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :subscriptions
end
```

This model would have 3 columns: id, subscription_id, and subscription_type_id, (and maybe a column subscription_type_name). Then make conventions like subscription_type_id of 1 is an email subscription, 2 is a magazine subscription or whatever, etc. Alternately, you could just add a subscription_type column in your subscription model.

For an easier time looking at what columns are in your models, use the [annotate gem](https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models), here's a quick tutorial on [how to use](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users?version=3.1#sec%3amodel_annotation)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't quite solve the problem.  The first is that I'm keeping subscriptions in a subdirectory and I'm not 100% certain I've referencing the class right.  Because I'll have multiple subscriptions I want to use a subdirectory.  The second is a subscription type won't work.  The email subscription for example actually supports 3 different types of emails the user might receive.  The EmailSub class has 3 different booleans in it.  The other subscription models will be similar, so I want to keep a distinct class for each in the subdirectory.